# Inclusion of Concurrent Chats Team Wise

Tags: sql

i am working on chat support data.
there is a agents chats with client but there is condition that one agent can chat max 3 client. so i want to take avg of Concurrent Chats.
For Example :-

```
Agent   Concurrent_Chats
Atul    1
Dinesh  2
Nimish  1
Nitesh  3
Atul    3
Ram     2
Rahul   4
```

Avg Concurrent_Chats    2.29

Comment: I don't understand how you arrive at `2.29`.  Can you explain it to us?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

You get the (overall (that's what your wanted ~2.29 suggests)) average simply by:

```
SELECT avg(concurrent_chats)
       FROM elbat;
```

But I don't see how that helps for checking if an agent hast more than three chats. I'd rather suggest something like

```
SELECT agent,
       concurrent_chats
       FROM elbat
       WHERE concurrent_chats > 3;
```

to get all agents who have more that three chats.